# Why would "poetry install --no-root" be used?

Tags: python-poetry

I already read [the documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/) in which it says

> The current project is installed in editable mode by default.
>
> If you want to install the dependencies only, run the `install`
> command with the `--no-root` flag:

What does `install --no-root` do?

In which cases would a user or developer use this instead of the normal install?

Should I use `--no-root` while still developing?

And if I want to install the project itself (one of the explanations) later, how can I do this?

Comment: That's a good question! I've never understood why one need `--no-root` and until now no one could explain it to me. The only use case I've found for me so far is https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#usecase-2

Comment: @finswimmer Maybe things like Django applications are a use case (they do not need to be installed, but their dependencies do need to be installed). -- In general there seems to be a need for projects that do not get built into a wheel, see this [discussion](https://discuss.python.org/t/projects-that-arent-meant-to-generate-a-wheel-and-pyproject-toml/29684) (and other related threads) if you have not seen it yet.

Comment: Adding to @sinoroc's comment: In code bases using $NON_PYTHON_LANGUAGE you might still want to use Python here and there for scripting purposes (e.g. build scripts and CI & CD jobs and such). In such cases, you won't have a coherent application (let alone a package or a wheel) but will still want to configure your Python environment somehow.

Comment: The comments on [Github](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2458) mention many other reasons why you might want to use `--no-root`.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience, I can think of a couple of use cases why for the `no-root` option.

1. To enhance a CI/CD pipeline. In that case, you'd be looking at having some sort of cache for the dependencies so that if the versions of the dependencies are unchanged, the installation is done from cache and the action sped up. Indeed, looking at the following:

```
- run: poetry install --no-interaction --no-root
   if: steps.cache-deps.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
```

it appears in some 250 github actions. This is almost always followed by
`- run: poetry install --no-interaction` for the actual package.

2. To separate layers of dependencies in cloud applications. For example, you may want to isolate your own package (which gets updated more often) from its dependencies in lambda layers in aws